# Rails Recursive Search Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a rails helper for this case?

You have a `Survey`, which `has_many` Questions, which `has_many` Answers.

```
s = Survey.first
s.answers # => Returns the answers of all the survey questions
```

I didn't want to recreate the wheel here.

Comment: A rails helper for WHAT case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built in:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions

  # ...
end
```

That's it. Now you can call `survey.answers` and it'll get all the answers.

Read up on the `:through` option (and its limitations) [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks Flambino, I use `through` frequently for my join tables, however, never ran into this use case. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: @Dru You're welcome. And, in this case, `questions` _is_ a join table - just think of it that way :)

Comment: This helped a lot. Such a simple solution when I thought it would be a massive.